# Google Sheets and App Script; Global Variable List/Array

Tags: javascript, list, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help with my Google AppsScript sheets program. Basically in my code, I need Trans2List to have elements appended from the function, RemoveDup2V1, which is called from the function, RemoveDup1. When I try to console.log the list in function, clean1, it return []. I have included a dummy sheet. Basically every time there is a Duplicate Trans AND Time, I need the second duplicate to be renamed to blank or anything, that is what clean1 does. Only duplicates are added to Trans2List and Time2List after two rows are compared. I think this is an issue with Global Array/List, but I am not sure nor do not know how to fix it. To run the clean1 function, I have added an menu to the sheet. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much for your effort and help! Let me know if anything else is needed.

Dummy Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nd1hUsOiX9eobjQzaVSQzsoWzEW7d-Fx27mHCmDeUw4/edit?usp=sharing

Google AppsScript Code:

```
var RemoveDupV1 = "";
var RemoveDubVV1 = "";
var Time2List = [];
var Trans2List = [];
var RemoveDupV2 = "";
var RemoveDupV3 = "";
var RemoveDupV4 = 0;
var RemoveDupV5 = 0;
var RemoveDupV6 = 0;

function RemoveDup1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      RemoveDup2V1(Trans2, Time2);
      return(Trans1);
    }else{
      return(Trans1)
    }
  }else{
    return(Trans1)
  }
}

function RDR1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2){
  RemoveDupV1 = RemoveDup1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2);
  return(RemoveDupV1)
}



function RemoveDup2V1(Trans2,Time2) {
  Trans2List.push(Trans2);
  Time2List.push(Time2);
}

function RemoveDup2(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      return(Time1);
    }else{
      return(Time1)
    }
  }else{
    return(Time1)
  }
}

function RDR2(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2){
  RemoveDupV2 = RemoveDup2(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2);
  return(RemoveDupV2)
}



function clean1() {
  console.log(Trans2List);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange('D:D').getDisplayValues();
  var range = [];
  var index = -1
  data.forEach(function(e, i){
    index = -1;
    if (e[0] == Trans2List[index + 1])
      if(e[1] == Time2List[index +1]) range.push("D" + (i + 1));
  });
  var newRange = [];
  for(var p = 0; p < range.length-1; p++){
    newRange.push(range[index+2]);
    index = index + 2;
  }
  sheet.getRangeList(newRange).clearContent();
}


function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Clear Dupes')
    .addItem('Clear All Dupes', 'clean1')
    .addSeparator()
    .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify your **main goal** here, is [this](https://imgur.com/a/Qg16og7) your desired expected result?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly how I would like it. If it’s easier, you can just just leave the Time, but Trans has to be blank. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted my test script as a suggested answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

I would recommend refactoring your script, as your current version involves multiple functions being used in different scenarios. For instance, you run the `RDR1` or `RDR2` as a custom function on your sheet, and then execute the `clean1` function through a custom menu.

***Sample refactored script***

```
function clean() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('A:B').getDisplayValues();

  var res = data.map((x, i, arr) => {
    try {
      return (x[0] == arr[i + 1][0] && x[1] == arr[i + 1][1]) ? ['', x[1]] : arr[i + 1];
    } catch {
    }
  }).filter(x => x);

  res.unshift(data[0])

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 4, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

***Demo***

> This script will place the result on column **D**.

[image]

***Reference***

- [JavaScript map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [JavaScript Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

Comment: That is very helpful! It just fixed my frustration! THANK YOU!!! Is it possible you could help me with one more thing related to this? If not, that's fine, I'll just make another post. But I have made a new dummy sheet. I have included the expected result and the current result with my current code. If you are able to help, thank you so much. The link is [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-B5YntWospkp-h62sss6b00PKejOuTX37Cif-i3PgFg/edit?usp=sharing). Once again, **THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!**

Comment: You're very welcome . Regarding that, you may need to submit it as another question. Thank you.

Comment: I have made a new post. Thanks again!