# Google Sheets and App Script; Adding multiple numbers with a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a new dummy sheet. I have included the expected result and the current result with my current code. I have tried with my best ability to try and code this, but it ultimately isn't working well for me. Basically, I need the blank Trans with quantities to be added to the one Trans. Same with price and discount. This is an extension of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922939/google-sheets-and-app-script-global-variable-list-array), so if you need some clarification, please check that as well. Let me know if you need some more info or help. If you are able to help, thank you so much. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much for your effort and help! Let me know if anything else is needed.

The link is [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-B5YntWospkp-h62sss6b00PKejOuTX37Cif-i3PgFg/edit?usp=sharing).

Note: Please ignore the variable/parameter "Category", since it is not related to this topic/question.

AppsScript Code:

```
var RemoveDupV1 = "";
var RemoveDubVV1 = "";
var Time2List = [];
var Trans2List = [];
var RemoveDupV2 = "";
var RemoveDupV3 = "";
var RemoveDupV4 = 0;
var RemoveDupV5 = 0;
var RemoveDupV6 = 0;

function RemoveDup1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      RemoveDup2V1(Trans2, Time2);
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('myArray', Trans2);
      return(Trans1);
    }else{
      return(Trans1)
    }
  }else{
    return(Trans1)
  }
}

function RDR1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2){
  RemoveDupV1 = RemoveDup1(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2);
  return(RemoveDupV1)
}

function RemoveDup2V1(Trans2,Time2) {
  Trans2List.push(Trans2);
  Time2List.push(Time2);
}


// Time
function RemoveDup2(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      return(Time1);
    }else{
      return(Time1)
    }
  }else{
    return(Time1)
  }
}

function RDR2(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2){
  RemoveDupV2 = RemoveDup2(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2);
  return(RemoveDupV2)
}



// Category
function RemoveDup3(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      return(Category);
    }else{
      return(Category)
    }
  }else{
    return(Category)
  }
}

function RDR3(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2){
  RemoveDupV3 = RemoveDup3(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2);
  return(RemoveDupV3)
}



// Quantity
function RemoveDup4(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      return(Quantity1 + Quantity2);
    }else{
      return(Quantity1)
    }
  }else{
    return(Quantity1)
  }
}

function RDR4(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2){
  RemoveDupV4 = RemoveDup4(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2);
  return(RemoveDupV4)
}



// Disc
function RemoveDup5(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      return(Disc1 + Disc2);
    }else{
      return(Disc1)
    }
  }else{
    return(Disc1)
  }
}

function RDR5(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2){
  RemoveDupV5 = RemoveDup5(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2);
  return(RemoveDupV5)
}



// Price
function RemoveDup6(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2) {
  if(Trans1.localeCompare(Trans2) == 0){
    if(Time1.localeCompare(Time2) == 0){
      return(Price1 + Price2);
    }else{
      return(Price1)
    }
  }else{
    return(Price1)
  }
}

function RDR6(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2){
  RemoveDupV6 = RemoveDup6(Trans1, Trans2, Time1, Time2, Category, Quantity1, Quantity2, Disc1, Disc2, Price1, Price2);
  return(RemoveDupV6)
}


function clean1() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:B11').getDisplayValues();

  var res = data.map((x, i, arr) => {
    try {
      return (x[0] == arr[i + 1][0] && x[1] == arr[i + 1][1]) ? ['', x[1]] : arr[i + 1];
    } catch {
    }
  }).filter(x => x);

  res.unshift(data[0])

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 7, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Clear Dupes')
    .addItem('Clear all Dupes', 'clean1')
    .addSeparator()
    .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: @Tanaike If you see the dummy sheet, you can see the expected result at the bottom, basically the transactions that are blank have one main transaction above them. The code need to output the correct quantity, discount amount, and price by adding it all up from the blank transactions. This should clarify it.

Comment: @Tanaike Please check my new comment on your answer. **Thank you very much for your help!!!***

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your reply of `I appreciate your answer, but it is a bit incorrect. Both functions are returning quantities added that are the same name. I have added a new sheet, please check Sheet2 using the same link. In that sheet I have added what need to be done.`

Comment: `For example, G4 is a name under it is a blank, the quantities, price, and discount of that blank need to be added to the G4. Same thing with G7. In G27, there are two blanks below it. The quantities, discounts, and prices of those two blanks need to be added to G27. All of these need to be repeated. I hope this clarifies everything. Thank you!`,

Comment: From `please check Sheet2 using the same link.`, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that your provided sample has been largely changed. In this case, my answer cannot be used. And also, I cannot understand your actual expected result. I deeply apologize that I couldn't notice that your sample input and output situations are different from your actual situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: My bad as well. I tried to explain using text, but it is pretty hard. You’re totally fine. But thanks for helping. Just let me know when you find an answer. **Thank you so much!!!**

Comment: @Tanaike it was mainly the same, but with different values and more unique names/times. It just makes it more realistic than before.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I could understand your this question, But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your actual expected result. By this, I cannot still think of a solution. I apologize for this. In order to understand your actual expected result, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect of your actual expected result?

Comment: Column G:K are what need to be used. Column M:Q include some examples of what I would like. Let me know if you need some more help. **Thanks!!!**

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your actual expected result, the sample input and output situations are columns "A" to "E" and columns "G" to "K", respectively. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: A:E is just to help me, just ignore it. G:K is my sample. M:Q is my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> If you see the dummy sheet, you can see the expected result at the bottom, basically the transactions that are blank have one main transaction above them. The code need to output the correct quantity, discount amount, and price by adding it all up from the blank transactions.

When your provided Spreadsheet is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script.

When you use this script in your provided Spreadsheet, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A1:E11)` into a cell. By this, the script is run and result values are returned.

```js
const SAMPLE = values =>
  [...values.reduce((m, r) => {
    const [a, , ...c] = r;
    if (m.has(a)) {
      const [aa, bb, ...cc] = m.get(a);
      m.set(a, [aa, bb, ...cc.map((e, i) => e + c[i])]);
    } else {
      m.set(a, r);
    }
    return m
  }, new Map()).values()];
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run with your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained. In this sample, I put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A1:E11)` into a cell "G14". The result can be seen in the red color range.

[image]

#### Note:

- If the number of rows is large, the custom function might not be able to be used. In that case, please run the script with the script editor. At that time, please use the following script.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const range = sheet.getDataRange();
    const values = [...range.getValues().reduce((m, r) => {
      const [a, , ...c] = r;
      if (m.has(a)) {
        const [aa, bb, ...cc] = m.get(a);
        m.set(a, [aa, bb, ...cc.map((e, i) => e + c[i])]);
      } else {
        m.set(a, r);
      }
      return m
    }, new Map()).values()];
    range.clearContent().offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

### Added 1:

From your following replies,

> but it is a bit incorrect. Both functions are returning quantities added that are the same name. I have added a new sheet, please check Sheet2 using the same link. In that sheet I have added what need to be done. For example, G4 is a name under it is a blank, the quantities, price, and discount of that blank need to be added to the G4. Same thing with G7. In G27, there are two blanks below it. The quantities, discounts, and prices of those two blanks need to be added to G27. All of these need to be repeated. I hope this clarifies everything.

> A:E is just to help me, just ignore it. G:K is my sample. M:Q is my output.

As one more sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script. And, put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(Sheet2!G1:K)` into a cell.

```js
const SAMPLE = v =>
  v.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    const [a, , ...c] = r;
    if (a.toString() == "") {
      const f1 = o.values[o.temp].splice(0, 2);
      o.values[o.temp] = [...f1, ...o.values[o.temp].map((e, j) => e + c[j])];
    } else {
      o.temp = i;
    }
    o.values.push(r);
    return o;
  }, { values: [], temp: -1 }).values;
```

If you want to directly run the script with the script editor, please use the following script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("G1:K" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const { values } = range.getValues().reduce((o, r, i) => {
    const [a, , ...c] = r;
    if (a.toString() == "") {
      const f1 = o.values[o.temp].splice(0, 2);
      o.values[o.temp] = [...f1, ...o.values[o.temp].map((e, j) => e + c[j])];
    } else {
      o.temp = i;
    }
    o.values.push(r);
    return o;
  }, { values: [], temp: -1 });
  range.offset(0, 6).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your 2nd expected result. Please be careful about this.

### Added 2:

From your following replies,

> PERFECT! But I need the value where it is blank/"", I need that row to be deleted. Then It is perfect. I forgot to mention that. Other than that, It is working well.

As one more sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script. And, put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(Sheet2!G1:K)` into a cell.

```js
const SAMPLE = v =>
  v.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    const [a, , ...c] = r;
    if (a.toString() == "") {
      const f1 = o.values[o.temp].splice(0, 2);
      o.values[o.temp] = [...f1, ...o.values[o.temp].map((e, j) => e + c[j])];
    } else {
      o.temp = i;
    }
    o.values.push(r);
    return o;
  }, { values: [], temp: -1 }).values.filter(([a]) => a);
```

If you want to directly run the script with the script editor, please use the following script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("G1:K" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().reduce((o, r, i) => {
    const [a, , ...c] = r;
    if (a.toString() == "") {
      const f1 = o.values[o.temp].splice(0, 2);
      o.values[o.temp] = [...f1, ...o.values[o.temp].map((e, j) => e + c[j])];
    } else {
      o.temp = i;
    }
    o.values.push(r);
    return o;
  }, { values: [], temp: -1 }).values.filter(([a]) => a);
  range.offset(0, 6, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it is a bit incorrect. Both functions are returning quantities added that are the same name. I have added a new sheet, please check Sheet2 using the same link.  In that sheet I have added what need to be done. For example, G4 is a name under it is a blank, the quantities, price, and discount of that blank need to be added to the G4. Same thing with G7. In G27, there are two blanks below it. The quantities, discounts, and prices of those two blanks need to be added to G27. All of these need to be repeated. I hope this clarifies everything. **Thank you!**

Comment: @Gurman3756 Thank you for replying. About your reply of `I appreciate your answer, but it is a bit incorrect. Both functions are returning quantities added that are the same name. I have added a new sheet, please check Sheet2 using the same link. In that sheet I have added what need to be done.`

Comment: @Gurman3756 `For example, G4 is a name under it is a blank, the quantities, price, and discount of that blank need to be added to the G4. Same thing with G7. In G27, there are two blanks below it. The quantities, discounts, and prices of those two blanks need to be added to G27. All of these need to be repeated. I hope this clarifies everything. Thank you!`,

Comment: @Gurman3756 From `please check Sheet2 using the same link.`, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that your provided sample has been largely changed. In this case, my answer cannot be used. And also, I cannot understand your actual expected result. I deeply apologize that I couldn't notice that your sample input and output situations are different from your actual situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Gurman3756 From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: PERFECT! But I need the value where it is blank/"", I need that row to be deleted. Then It is perfect. I forgot to mention that. Other than that, It is working well. **Thanks so much!!!**

Comment: @Gurman3756 Thank you for replying. About `PERFECT! But I need the value where it is blank/"", I need that row to be deleted. Then It is perfect. I forgot to mention that. Other than that, It is working well. Thanks so much!!!`, do you wanted to delete when the value of column "G" is empty?

Comment: Yes. But the quantities, discount, and price should be added, exactly how it is now.

Comment: @Gurman3756 From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: It is working wonders right now! Thank you so much for your help. I know how hard it must be to understand another language, but I really appreciate how you still tried and helped me all the way through. I will always remember this. I hope you have a blessed day and life. Once again, **THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!**